# How to restrict a Node API running in Elastic Beanstalk to be consumed only by a specific domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The question is probably self-explanatory, but the website that consumes the API also has the same TLD, and is also hosted within AWS.

The API doesn't return sensitive data, I just want to prevent someone else using my API.

I think this is something for the AWS end rather than the Node side.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about AWS but you can use cors in node to only allow specific domains to access your server.
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of restricting your api is through applying CORS policy. Allowing cors only for specific domain but this method will not restrict usage of api completely because cors are enforced by browsers only. Someone will still be able to consume your api through postman or curl.

Another method is to use authentication techniques which include session based on cookie or jwt to access endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

To complement other answers, you can also consider proxing your API through **API Gateway** by means of [HTTP_PROXY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) integration.

The API Gateway enables for **fine grain control** of access, caching and throttling of the api. These can be achieved using:

- [API KEYS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html)
- [Authorizers](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/)
- [API access policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html)